# How to find rows with the same values in multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

There is a table with 97972561 rows (recordings) and 8 columns (attributes). The format looks like:

```
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| PREDICATE_ID | PMID | SENTENCE_ID | SUBJECT_ID | SUBJECT_NAME | PREDICATE | OBJECT_ID | OBJECT_NAME |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I would like to filter recordings whose subject, predication and object value only appear once. For example, there are four recordings in a table. The last recording should be excluded from the result because (Bob, is_a, Person) only appears once.

```
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| PREDICATE_ID | PMID | SENTENCE_ID | SUBJECT_ID | SUBJECT_NAME | PREDICATE | OBJECT_ID | OBJECT_NAME |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 1            | 100  | 1           | 2          | Bob          | is_born_in| 3         | 1994        |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 1            | 103  | 3           | 2          | Bob          | is_born_in| 3         | 1994        |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 1            | 102  | 5           | 2          | Bob          | is_born_in| 3         | 1994        |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2            | 104  | 2           | 2          | Bob          | is_a      | 4         | Person      |
+--------------+------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Filtered or deleted, as in you want them to be excluded from your query result, or deleted from the table entirely?

Comment: I want them to be excluded. @MichaelNovello

Comment: Why would a table store both the subject_id and the subject- likewise for predicate and object!?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation, we can try:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBJECT_ID, PREDICATE_ID, OBJECT_ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID, PREDICATE_ID, OBJECT_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.SUBJECT_ID = t2.SUBJECT_ID AND
       t1.PREDICATE_ID = t2.PREDICATE_ID AND
       t1.OBJECT_ID = t2.OBJECT_ID;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, we can leverage analytical functions for a cleaner looking query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BY SUBJECT_ID, PREDICATE_ID, OBJECT_ID) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Where are you getting `t2` from? It looks like he's just using one table.

Comment: I am running it. It seems to work. Because there are too many recordings in the table, so it takes time. Will accept it after the result returns. Thank you.